# installing and using ffmpeg-php in my wamp apache

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg, php-extension

[image]hey there i am developing a video sharing site and i need to change the video format and get its thumbnail etc i know this can be done by ffmpeg-php library.

but i have never used any php lib before .
i have successfully installed ffmpeg to my system (laptop) i can check it by typing library ffmpeg -version to my comand prompt it says something like this

```
  Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

   C:\Windows\system32>ffmpeg -version
  ffmpeg version N-73818-g9ebe041 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
    built with gcc 4.9.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --      enable-avis
  ynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable
   -iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --en
 able-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-lib
     ilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable
 -libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enab
    le-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enabl
   e-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc -
     -enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-
    libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enabl
   e-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      54. 28.100 / 54. 28.100
  libavcodec     56. 49.101 / 56. 49.101
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
 libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
 libavfilter     5. 25.100 /  5. 25.100
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
   libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
```

but i am having problem with accessing the library by my php code i think i have't installed it to my php module

here is what my wamp shows me

```
  Server Configuration
  Apache Version :
  2.4.9   - Documentation
  PHP Version :
   5.5.12   - Documentation
   Server Software:
    Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12
       Loaded Extensions :
            apache2handlerbcmathbz2calendarcom_dotnetCorectypecurlda
     tedomeregexiffileinfofil[![enter image description here][1]][1]terftpgdgettextgmphashiconvimapjsonlib
      xmlmbstringmcryptmhashmysqlmysqlimysqlndod
      bcopensslpcrePDOpdo_mysqlpdo_sqlitePharReflectio
     nsessionshmopSimpleXMLsoapsocket    sSPLsqlite3standardtokenizerwddxxdebugxmlxmlreaderxmlrpcxmlwriterxslzipzlib
       MySQL Version :
       5.6.17  -  Documentation
```

if possible please tell me the next step so that i can access the ffmpeg lib from my php code .
a little help is also appreciated.
1.please tell me any link availabe to get the ffmpeg-php module and how to installl it
2.how to access the module/lib from my code justa small code example.

THANK YOU.